# Is it okay to have multiple contexts for one component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently creating a date picker as my first React project and I need some data to be shared across a lot of components and sub components to avoid prop drilling.

For instance, I have a context for the date picker view (day, month or year), a context for the variant (desktop or mobile) a context for storing the selected date and a context for the current month of the date picker.

But I'm just scared to have too many contexts mostly for a single component so it is a problem in React ?

Comment: No, it is not a problem in react js.

Comment: Sure, a context provider is just another component in the ReactTree.